# flutter problem: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween not working for Row,

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

### I want spaceBetween two text  which is in Row.I want like my actuall ui (second one).

I want spaceBetween two text  which is in Row.I want like my actuall ui (second one).
I want spaceBetween two text  which is in Row.I want like my actuall ui (second one).
I want spaceBetween two text  which is in Row.I want like my actuall ui (second one).

this is my code of list

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (context, position) {

          return  Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0,right: 20,bottom:10,top: 10 ),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 40,
                      width: 40,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.circular(50),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage(
                                'assets/dummy5.png',
                              ),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                      //child: Image.asset("lib/Assets/clinic.png")
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 10,),
                    Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text("Model Portfolio",style: TextStyle(fontSize: tSize16,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,color: blackColor),),

                            Text("Total Value",style: TextStyle(fontSize: tSize16,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,color: blackColor),),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10,),
                        Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text("Portfolio no.: 6",style: TextStyle(fontSize: tSize13,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,color: skyBlue),),
                            Text("₹ 52,02,990",style: TextStyle(fontSize: tSize13,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,color: green2Color),),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                )),
              Divider()
            ],
          );
        }
        ),
      )
```

this is my ui which i created
[image]

In Actual i want like this, I want spacing like this,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows:

```
Card(
        child: SizedBox(
           width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 150,
            child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                  height: 40,
                  width: 40,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.circular(50),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage(
                            'assets/dummy5.png',
                          ),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                 
                ),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: const [
                    Text("title 1"),
                    Text("title 2"),
                  ]),
                  Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: const [
                    Text("Rs 123"),
                    Text("-4524"),
                  ]),
                ]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ListView.separated` for divider. I've changed a change the widget decoration, you can follow this widget.

```dart
ListView.separated(
  // shrinkWrap: true,
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  itemCount: 10,
  separatorBuilder: (_, index) => Divider(),
  itemBuilder: (context, position) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 40,
          width: 40,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
              color: Colors.cyanAccent
              // image: DecorationImage(
              //   image: AssetImage(
              //     'assets/dummy5.png',
              //   ),
              //   fit: BoxFit.cover,
              // ),
              ),
          //child: Image.asset("lib/Assets/clinic.png")
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Model Portfolio",
                    style: TextStyle(),
                  ),
                  Text("holding QTy $position"),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Total Value",
                    style: TextStyle(),
                  ),
                  Text(" V: $position"),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }),
```

[image]

Comment: If it is possible, skip using `shrinkWrap: true,`